# How do I create a unique record id in a python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe, where I want a unique id (rec_id) for every record.
Something like

[picture of the troublesome df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkO8N.png)

I have been experiementing with rec_id=df.index, but index was not unique
Have tried to reset it with df.reset_index().
not good either.

Any suggestions are warmly welcomed.

BR Lasse

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ds = ds.assign(rec_id=np.arange(len(ds))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Jova', 'Mimi', 'Taty', 'Jessica', 'Alex'],
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014],
        'docs': [40, 24, 19, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['bg', 'ny', 'sd', 'sp', 'la'])

print (df)

print (df.name.unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this in lack of a prettier solution.

```
    colle=ds.columns
    ds=ds.values
    ds=pd.DataFrame(ds)
    ds.columns=colle
    ds['rec_id']=ds.index
```